# React implement activity wheel while waiting on API call to return data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, spinner, react-bootstrap

Just trying to return some data from the Magic the Gathering API (super fun game by the way). The api is a little slow to return data when I try to make a call to get some cards by searching for them.

I have a react bootstrap modal that pops up whenever I search a term. I'd like to render a spinner in it while I'm waiting to get the cards back, then remove it once some cards show up.

I was thinking that I could just display the spinner while my cards array was empty or undefined but since there's a pending promise representing the value I don't think that'll work?

Can someone help me out with the best way to do this?

```
state = {
  modal: false,
  form: "",
  result: []
};

// function to get cards from the api and update the state

cardsLoaded = () => {
  if (this.state.result === [] || this.state.result === undefined) {
    return (
      <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
        <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </Spinner>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "block", width: "10em" }}>
        {this.state.result.map((card, section, index, add) => {
          return (
            <div key={section} style={{ display: "inline" }}>
              <button key={index}>{card}</button>
              <button key={add} onClick={() => this.props.addToDeck(card)}>
                <GiCardPlay />
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

here is my modal where I am rendering the spinner:

```
<Modal
  show={this.state.modal}
  onExit={() => console.log("modal closed")}
  size="lg"
  aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
  centered
>
  <Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">Modal heading</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>

  <Modal.Body>{() => this.cardsLoaded()}</Modal.Body>
  <Modal.Footer>
    <Button onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>;
```

Comment: You are comparing arrays by reference. Empty array literal will never be equal to another one (`if (this.state.result === [])`). Try to use `array.length` in your conditional instead.

Comment: Agreed with @HynekS. Another option is having your API call set a "loading flag" for rendering your spinner and then when the api call resolves, it can clear the flag. Although, this may or may not be trivial to do depending on how your components are structured.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to set a "loading" flag when you call your API and then clear it when your API call is resolved?

```js
// set loading flag to true while fetching from API
this.setState({ loading: true });

// fetch from api, set flag to false once the api call resolves 
// (whether it's successful or not)
fetch('http://apiuri.com/')
  .then(res => {
    // handle response here...
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // handle error here...
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  })
```

Then where you are rendering your `Spinner`, you can render it conditionally with the `loading` flag.

```js
this.state.loading && (
  <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
    <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
  </Spinner>
)
```

You may have to shuffle some state/props around depending on your component hierarchy